# Excel cannot assign macro to a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my excel file (I think it's corrupted). In one file, I cannot assign a new or an existing macro to any new buttons. I get the error that the macro cannot be found, even though it is definitely saved in the right place. At the same time existing buttons work with existing macros, only new ones don't with neither new macros or old ones. What can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Do you get the error when you assign the macro, or when you try to run it from the button?

Comment: Is the macro a `Sub` **without** arguments? Because you cannot assign procedures or functions to a button if they have arguments.

Comment: Are the macros in the workbook and not recorded somewhere else?   Can you call them from immediate window in VBE?

Comment: Please post the line of code where you define your sub so we can see what you are trying to call.

Comment: @Rory when I try to run it. But the problem is that it happens when I try to run any macro.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it is without arguments yes. I recorded the macro

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I can call them from immediate window in VBA. Furthermore, not even the macros that I know work, are working in this case

Comment: @k1dfr0std these are the macros I am trying to assign:Sub Change_to_general_format()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("E12:AI12").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("C10:AI13").Copy
    Range("C14:AI129").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Comment: Make sure it is declared public and it is located in a standard module: `Public Sub Change_to_general_format()`. Try it with a brand new Excel file so you are sure it is not related to some corrupt file. Try with your file on another computer to exclude issues with your Office installation.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think it is a corrupt file. It is working on new documents etc.

Comment: Try the following: Open your file. Chose Save-As from the menu. Select the binary `xlsb` format and save the file. Then close Excel re-open the `xlsb` file and try again. If it works you can try to re-save that `xlsb` file in the `xlsm` format. Sometimes this repairs corrupt files. Might work or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to move the excel file to a different location and it worked.

Comment: Your question stated "it is definitely saved in the right place". :-)

Comment: Actually that does not make any sense at all.

Comment: I've seen all kinds of weird garbage happen once a file has been saved in OneDrive.  Also, find other ways to clean up your code by removing the `Select` items, and get in the habit of fully qualifying your ranges.  Glad you got it working!